# Error en script para calcular la media geométrica

Tags: pandas, numpy, python-3.7

Disponemos de un DataFrame denominado **tabla**. queremos calcular la media geométrica de una distribución de frecuencia con intervalos de clase., aplicando la fórmula. $$\sigma = \widetilde {x}_g = \sqrt[N]{x_1^{f_1} * x_2^{f_2} *...* x_n^{fn}}$$ .

Este script lo hace correctamente.

```
tabla = {'LimitesExactos' : ["10-30", "30-50", "50-70", "70-90", "90-110" ], 
         'Xi' : [20, 40, 60, 80, 100], 'fi' : [5, 7, 10, 12, 6]}
tabla = pd.DataFrame(tabla, dtype = np.float64)
sumaFi = tabla['fi'].sum()
num = 1
for i in range (0, tabla.shape[0]):
    a = tabla['Xi'][i] ** tabla['fi'][i]
    #a = np.float64(a)  # para evitar desbordamiento
    num = num * a
media_geometrica_1 = (num)**(1/tabla['fi'].sum())
print (tabla, "\n")
print ("\nMedia geométrica", media_geometrica_1)
```

Intentamos mejorarlo con numpy, teniendo encuenta que necesitamos calcular primero el valor medio de cada intervalo de clase. Lo intentamos así.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tabla = {'LimitesExactos': ["10-30", "30-50", "50-70", "70-90", "90-110"],
         'Xi': [20, 40, 60, 80, 100],
         'fi': [5, 7, 10, 12, 6]}
tabla = pd.DataFrame(tabla)

# Convertir las columnas 'Xi' y 'fi' a tipo numérico
tabla['Xi'] = pd.to_numeric(tabla['Xi'])
tabla['fi'] = pd.to_numeric(tabla['fi'])

# Calcular el valor medio de cada intervalo de clase
tabla['Xi'] = (tabla['LimitesExactos'].str.split('-')
                .apply(lambda x: np.array(x, dtype=np.float64)).sum(axis=1)) / 2

# Calcular la media geométrica
num = np.prod(tabla['Xi'] ** tabla['fi'])
media_geom = num ** (1 / np.sum(tabla['fi']))

# Calcular la desviación estándar geométrica
desv_geom = (num ** (1 / np.sum(tabla['fi']))) ** np.sqrt(np.sum(tabla['fi'] * np.log(tabla['Xi'] / media_geom) ** 2) / np.sum(tabla['fi']))

print(tabla)
print("Media geométrica:", media_geom)
print("Desviación estándar geométrica:", desv_geom)
```

Me devuelve el siguiente error.

---

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:554, in NDFrame._get_axis_number(cls, axis)
553 try:
--> 554     return cls._AXIS_TO_AXIS_NUMBER[axis]
555 except KeyError:

KeyError: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 14
     11 tabla['fi'] = pd.to_numeric(tabla['fi'])
     13 # Calcular el valor medio de cada intervalo de clase
---> 14 tabla['Xi'] = (tabla['LimitesExactos'].str.split('-')
     15                 .apply(lambda x: np.array(x, dtype=np.float64)).sum(axis=1)) / 2
     17 # Calcular la media geométrica
     18 num = np.prod(tabla['Xi'] ** tabla['fi'])

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:11797, in NDFrame._add_numeric_operations.<locals>.sum(self, axis, skipna, level, numeric_only, min_count, **kwargs)
  11777 @doc(
  11778     _num_doc,
  11779     desc="Return the sum of the values over the requested axis.\n\n"
   (...)
  11795     **kwargs,
  11796 ):
> 11797     return NDFrame.sum(
  11798         self, axis, skipna, level, numeric_only, min_count, **kwargs
  11799     )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:11501, in NDFrame.sum(self, axis, skipna, level, numeric_only, min_count, **kwargs)
  11492 def sum(
  11493     self,
  11494     axis: Axis | None = None,
   (...)
  11499     **kwargs,
  11500 ):
> 11501     return self._min_count_stat_function(
  11502         "sum", nanops.nansum, axis, skipna, level, numeric_only, min_count, **kwargs
  11503     )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:11483, in NDFrame._min_count_stat_function(self, name, func, axis, skipna, level, numeric_only, min_count, **kwargs)
  11467     warnings.warn(
  11468         "Using the level keyword in DataFrame and Series aggregations is "
  11469         "deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use groupby "
   (...)
  11472         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
  11473     )
  11474     return self._agg_by_level(
  11475         name,
  11476         axis=axis,
   (...)
  11480         numeric_only=numeric_only,
  11481     )
> 11483 return self._reduce(
  11484     func,
  11485     name=name,
  11486     axis=axis,
  11487     skipna=skipna,
  11488     numeric_only=numeric_only,
  11489     min_count=min_count,
  11490 )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:4793, in Series._reduce(self, op, name, axis, skipna, numeric_only, filter_type, **kwds)
   4790 delegate = self._values
   4792 if axis is not None:
-> 4793     self._get_axis_number(axis)
   4795 if isinstance(delegate, ExtensionArray):
   4796     # dispatch to ExtensionArray interface
   4797     return delegate._reduce(name, skipna=skipna, **kwds)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:556, in NDFrame._get_axis_number(cls, axis)
    554     return cls._AXIS_TO_AXIS_NUMBER[axis]
    555 except KeyError:
--> 556     raise ValueError(f"No axis named {axis} for object type {cls.__name__}")

ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type Series
```

¿Cuál puede ser la causa?. Cómo puedo fijarlo?. Es coorecto el script?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

En la documentación de [`pandas.Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) se puede leer lo siguiente:

> Parameters axis{index (0)} Axis for the function to be applied on. For
> Series this parameter is unused and defaults to 0.

Es decir, el eje en las series no se utiliza, además las series tienen un solo eje, que sería el vertical y al ser un único eje su valor es `0`.

Los `dataframes`, por otra parte, tienen dos ejes, que serían los índices, es decir las filas (Horizontal) que tiene valor `0` y las columnas (Vertical) que tiene el valor `1`.

No entiendo muy bien el motivo para recalcular "Xi", si ya viene como parte del `dataset`, pero tendrías que aplicar la suma y la división en cada fila, es decir, adentro del `apply`, de esta forma:

```
tabla['LimitesExactos'].str.split('-').apply(lambda x: np.array(x, dtype=np.float64).sum()/2)
```

O lo que vendría siendo el promedio de los datos de la lista de cada fila que se podría simplificar al utilizar `mean`.

```
tabla['LimitesExactos'].str.split('-').apply(lambda x: np.array(x, dtype=np.float64).mean())
```

**Nota adicional:** No sé si fue error al redactar la pregunta pero la línea:

```
tabla = pd.DataFrame(tabla, dtype = np.float64)
```

No funciona, ya que conviertes todas las columnas a `np.float64` pero como "LimitesExactos" es `string` te devolverá error.

Lo mejor es utilizar un diccionario para cambiar el tipo de dato a las columnas que se desea, de esta forma:

```
convert_dict = {
                'Xi': np.float64,
                'fi': np.float64
               }

tabla = tabla.astype(convert_dict)
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tabla = {'LimitesExactos': ["10-30", "30-50", "50-70", "70-90", "90-110"],
         'Xi': [20, 40, 60, 80, 100],
         'fi': [5, 7, 10, 12, 6]}
tabla = pd.DataFrame(tabla)

convert_dict = {
                'Xi': np.float64,
                'fi': np.float64
               }
tabla = tabla.astype(convert_dict)

# Calcular el valor medio de cada intervalo de clase
tabla['Xi2'] = tabla['LimitesExactos'].str.split('-').apply(lambda x: np.array(x, dtype=np.float64).mean())

# Calcular la media geométrica
num = np.prod(tabla['Xi'] ** tabla['fi'])
media_geom = num ** (1 / np.sum(tabla['fi']))

# Calcular la desviación estándar geométrica
desv_geom = (num ** (1 / np.sum(tabla['fi']))) ** np.sqrt(np.sum(tabla['fi'] * np.log(tabla['Xi'] / media_geom) ** 2) / np.sum(tabla['fi']))

print(tabla)
print("Media geométrica:", media_geom)
print("Desviación estándar geométrica:", desv_geom)
```

Esto imprime:

```
  LimitesExactos     Xi    fi    Xi2
0          10-30   20.0   5.0   20.0
1          30-50   40.0   7.0   40.0
2          50-70   60.0  10.0   60.0
3          70-90   80.0  12.0   80.0
4         90-110  100.0   6.0  100.0
Media geométrica: 57.33952047130464
Desviación estándar geométrica: 7.315488246506205
```